# What defines a "persistent" data structure in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

The http://clojure.org/data_structures page explains all Clojure collections as being "immutable and persistent". I have been looking for a clear definition of exactly what "persistent" means in this instance and whether anybody has a clear explanation of this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It refers to the same kind of persistent as [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) wikipedia article. Summarized:

> In computing, a persistent data structure is a data structure that
>   always preserves the previous version of itself when it is modified.
>   Such data structures are effectively immutable, as their operations do
>   not (visibly) update the structure in-place, but instead always yield
>   a new updated structure. (A persistent data structure is not a data
>   structure committed to persistent storage, such as a disk; this is a
>   different and unrelated sense of the word "persistent.")

Comment: another point worth nothing about the Clojure version is that they use structural sharing to reduce the heap usage overhead of immutability

Comment: Is it possible to have a structure that is immutable but not persistent?

Comment: You could always copy a lot :)